# Android Google Sign In: Two different server Client id Provided

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, backend, google-signin

I am trying to integrate Google Sign-In on my Android application and website.

I integrated them separately, and while integrating it on website, I received a server client id through which I integrated the backend of it as well.

Now when integrating it in Android using Firebase and downloading the Google configuration Gson from console and passing the same server side client id in `GoogleSignInoptions.requestIDToken`, it crashes the app saying there are two server side id clients provided.

I am not really sure how to correct this. My error:

```
Process: com.example.ayush.bottomnavigation, PID: 23326
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ayush.bottomnavigation/com.example.ayush.bottomnavigation.SignInActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: two different server client ids provided
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: two different server client ids provided
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzab.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions$Builder.zzfs(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions$Builder.requestIdToken(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.ayush.bottomnavigation.SignInActivity.onCreate(SignInActivity.java:64)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue.

Comment: any updates for this please?